# Does there exist a firefox.tar.bz2 package for Raspi (!ARM!) which can be downloaded? (Making firefox "portable" on Raspi)

Tags: apt, software-installation, firefox, raspberrypi, arm

I know there exists a firefox-esr package for Raspberry Pi OS and firefox is also preinstalled on Ubuntu Mint [Raspi-Image].

But in this case I'm trying to get firefox as a .tar.bz2 package from the official release site: https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

My goal is, to be able to create a "kinda portable" firefox directory.
On my main PC I download the .bz2 package from here:
https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/90.0/linux-x86_64/de/

Then I extract it and can create a script which starts firefox, but saves all of the data in a defined directory!:

```
#!/bin/sh
"path/to/firefox/firefox" -no-remote -profile "path/to/profilefolder"
```

But on Raspi I can only run ARM stuff (sorry for this choice of words, I'm not even one year using linux, excuse :/ ) so this formats/packages:

Dir     linux-i686/
Dir     linux-x86_64/

... won't start on the Raspi :| (I tried the firefox runtime/application in the firefox folder, but it didn't start.

It would mean the world to me, being able to change the profile-data path without taking to deep changes in the OS. So this script workaround is already good- if you have any tips, I would be really happy to hear from you!

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu Mint.  Ubuntu also has *flavors* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) which does **not** include Mint.  Raspberry Pi OS is like not Ubuntu and off-topic here, please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: This question seems on-topic to me. The references to non-Ubuntu distros look like examples of Firefox on other distros to me, not questions about those distros.

Comment: excuse me! It was late and I was kinda tired ... I was talking about ubuntu mate of corse! So sorry for that :(

Comment: if your question is wrong; your should correct it. Currently the only OSes mentioned as Raspberry Pi OS & Ubuntu/[Linux] Mint which is not a *flavor* of Ubuntu.  On-topic *flavors* can be found [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours); none of which appear in your current question.

Answer (score 2):

I have a tip for you that might work.

You can start firefox like this:

`firefox --profile /path/to/profile`

Interestingly, you can also just use:

`firefox --profile .`

Where `.` tells it to use the current directory as the profile. That way, if it was on a USB drive for example, it would be portable, as long as you launched it that way. All the data would be tied to the current directory where it was launched from.